# Can not access Json Array Response

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hey im having an issue with an API im trying to integrate...

I have this code:

```
    $deleteOld = $facepp->execute('/person/delete', array('person_name' => $id));
    $response = $facepp->execute('/person/create', array('person_name' => $id));
    print_r($response);
    echo $response['body']['person_id'];
```

the print_r output is

```
Array
(
    [http_code] => 200
    [request_url] => http://apius.faceplusplus.com//person/create
    [body] => {
    "added_face": 0, 
    "added_group": 0, 
    "person_id": "00c812cbd9c763a6dae36a48bc54b855", 
    "person_name": "3824", 
    "tag": ""
}
)
```

I want to return the person_id, but all i get is "{"

SOLUTION:

```
$response = $facepp->execute('/person/create', array('person_name' => $id));
print_r($response);
$response = json_decode($response['body'], true);
echo $response['person_id'];
```

Comment: The element `body` contains a json string, which you first need to decode.

Comment: thx a lot, solved!

Answer (score 0):

You have to user json_decode() function then it will converted into array

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
$response = $facepp->execute('/person/create', array('person_name' => $id));
print_r($response);
$response = json_decode($response['body'], true);
echo $response['person_id'];
```